# SVGZ file format

Tags: svg, svgz

I'm working in SVG and just read about the compressed file 'SVGZ' format. As it makes our file sizes a lot smaller, I'm quite keen on using it in our web application, however the browsers do not appear to support the format. Can anyone point to any documentation on how to use SVGZ files instead of SVG in online documents/ apps.

Answer (score 35):

`SVGZ` is just a gzipped `SVG`, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics#Compression).

**Note**: Not all browser support `SVGZ`. Your HTTP server may probably compresses its response with deflate, which have the same performance.

Comment: All browsers support SVGZ when served with the proper HTTP headers.

Comment: Er, aren’t there actually a small number of browsers that can’t do gzip, Erik?

Comment: Erik, by all browsers, do you also mean older ones — say IE8?

Comment: IE8 doesn't support SVG, so it makes no sense to try gzip (for SVGZ). http://caniuse.com/svg

Comment: Compressing with deflate each time a SVG file is sent does not have the same performance and ressource usage on server.

Comment: The link is outdated. See also http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/intro.html#MIMEType

Comment: @bokan, web servers keep compressed outputs at a cache, at least IIS does. So they're not compressed each time they are served.

Answer (score 8):

As SVG is just plain-text you are able to send it from your server in a compressed format.

[Enable Gzip Compression on Apache](http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/)

Look into gzip/deflate compression for your particular http server, the support for compression in browsers is very good at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

Also SVGZ files cannot be opened locally by Firefox 19.0.2 or IE 9.0.8112, however, Google Chrome can. This doesn't necessarily effect people viewing it through your browser since it ought to work if you set the right mime-type, but if they download it they will not be able to open it regularily (until they un-gzip it of course).

Comment: Also Firefox 27.0 and IE 11.0 cannot open local svgz files. However, Chrome and Opera can.